# How to fix multiple definition erorr?

Tags: c, header-files, function-definition, function-declaration

In my code (using code blocks) it kept saying multiple definition in every function in wagon.c

I try change so much var in .h and main but it useless.  I'm not that good in English nor in code ^^ so please any help or some sites to learn this chapter to improve my skills.

I have the .h and its good

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "wagon.h"

void saisir_wagon(wagon *w) //here there is a multipel definition how``
{
  printf("donner un numero\n");
  scanf("%d", &w->num);
  do {
    printf("donner le type\n");
    gets(w->type);
  } while ((strcmp(w->type, "wagon") != 0)
      && (strcmp(w->type, "locomotive" != 0)));
  do {
    printf("donner l etat \n");
    scanf("%d", &w->ok);
  } while ((w->ok = !0) && (w->ok = !1));
}

LIST ajout_deb(wagon w, LIST l) {
  struct cellule *nouv;

  nouv = malloc(sizeof(wagon));

  if (l != NULL) {
    nouv->w = w;
    nouv->suiv = l;
  } else {
    nouv->suiv = NULL;
    l = nouv;
  }

  return l;
}

LIST ajout_queue(wagon W, LIST l) {
  struct cellule *nouv, *parc;

  nouv = malloc(sizeof(cellule));
  nouv->w = W;
  nouv->suiv = NULL;

  if (l == NULL) {
    l = nouv;
  } else {
    parc = l;
    while (parc->suiv != NULL) {
      parc = parc->suiv;
    }
    parc->suiv = nouv;
  }
  return (l);
}

void parkour_l(LIST l) {
  struct cellule *tmp = l;
  if (l == NULL)
    printf("liste vide /n");
  else {
    while (tmp != NULL) {
      printf("le numero :%d /n", tmp->w.num);
      printf("le type :%s /n", tmp->w.type);
      printf("l'etat: %d /n", tmp->w.ok);
      tmp = tmp->suiv;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Move function definitions from the header in a C module.

Comment: Given that `#include "wagon.h"`, are you showing the header (`.h` file) or the `.c` file? Please post both. Does the header have [include guards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27810115/what-exactly-do-c-include-guards-do)?

Answer (score 0):

The reason of the error is that you placed function definitions in a header that is included more than one module. As a result the functions are defined more than one time.

Remove the function definitions from the header and place them in a module.

The header should have only function declarations without their definitions if the functions are declared without the function specifier inline.

Pay attention to that the function `gets` is unsafe and is not supported by the C Standard.

Also in the condition expression

```
 } while ((w->ok = !0) && (w->ok = !1));
```

it seems there is a typo.

Maybe you mean

```
 } while ((w->ok != 0) && (w->ok != 1));
```

It seems there is another typo

```
  struct cellule *nouv;

  nouv = malloc(sizeof(wagon));
```

Maybe you need to write

```
  nouv = malloc(sizeof( struct cellule ));
```

And maybe this if-else statement

```
  if (l != NULL) {
    nouv->w = w;
    nouv->suiv = l;
  } else {
    nouv->suiv = NULL;
    l = nouv;
  }
```

should be rewritten like one if statement.

```
  if (l != NULL) {
    nouv->w = w;
    nouv->suiv = l;
    l = nouv;
  }
```

That is it seems there are several problems with your function definitions.