# how to solve unterminated ifndef?

Tags: c

How can I solve the `error: unterminated #ifndef` when am trying to use header files with my defined functions in C ?

```
In file included from test.c:1:
main.h:1: error: unterminated #ifndef
    1 | # ifndef _MAIN_H_
      |
```

this is the code

```
# ifndef _MAIN_H_
# ifdef _MAIN_H_

int now(void);

# endif
~
```

I though #endif solves it all but failed.

Comment: " #endif solves it all" `#endif` closes exactly one `#if` or `#else` or `#elif`. Not all that are open.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverlow. Please take a [tour] and see [ask]. Specifically you'll need to post a [mre]. In general `#endif` does close [one] `#ifndef` but without seeing your code it's hard to say what went wrong.

Comment: ``` C  # ifndef _MAIN_H_
# ifdef _MAIN_H_

int now(void);

# endif

Comment: Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27810115/what-exactly-do-c-include-guards-do

Answer (score 3):

The `#ifdef` should be a `#define` for you to have working #include guard.  As originally written the `#ifndef` is missing the matching `#endif`.

Symbols that start with underscore followed by an uppercase letter are reserved (6.4.2.1).  Use MAIN_H instead.

You could also use `#pragma once` which is a non-standard, but widely supported, alternative to the include guard.

Leave out the `~` of the code listing as it's vi's EOF marker and not part of your header file.

Comment: Regarding search for dupes, there's usually no need for that, just go to https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c/info, scratch your head for a second: "this would be a question about the preprocessor", scroll down to FAQ -> preprocessor, grab [Creating your own header file in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7109964/creating-your-own-header-file-in-c), copy/pasta into close as dupe. In this case I voted to close the question as simple typo since it's unlikely that the particular problem of the OP is a recurring one.

Comment: @Lundin LOL.  It took me an embarrassing long time to figure how to navigate to that page (click or search for tag, then click "Learn more...").